# request in PhpMyAdmin works, with Laravel Query Builder, doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel, query-builder

I have a problem that I can't fix :

this request works in PHPMYADMIN

```
SELECT cronState.name, command.name, parameter.keyword, eventParameterValue.value
FROM cronState, commandInstance, command, eventParameterValue, parameter
WHERE cronState.id = commandInstance.cronState_id
AND commandInstance.command_id = command.id
AND eventParameterValue.commandInstance_id = commandInstance.id
AND eventParameterValue.parameter_id = parameter.id
AND cronState.id =32
```

it returns :

```
name    name            keyword     value   

on20    DigitalPinSet   State       1
on20    PwmPinSet       DutyCycle   20
```

and it's ALL I want.

**LITTLE EDIT : I use an AJAX Request(with a state_name) to this method which should returns the query result.**

Now, when I try to implement it with the Laravel Query Builder, it returns some errors.

My code:

```
    $cronState_id = DB::table('cronState')
        ->where('name', Input::get('state_name'))
        ->first();
    $cronEvent = DB::table('cronState')
        ->join('commandInstance', 'commandInstance.cronState_id', '=', 'cronState.id')
        ->join('command', 'commandInstance.command_id', '=', 'command.id')
        ->join('eventParameterValue', 'eventParameterValue.commandInstance_id', '=', 'commandInstance.id')
        ->join('eventParameterValue', 'eventParameterValue.parameter_id', '=', 'parameter.id')
        ->where('cronState.id', '=', $cronState_id->id)
        ->select('cronState.name', 'command.name', 'parameter.keyword', 'eventParameterValue.value');

foreach($cronEvent as $result){
        $ev =  $result['keyword'];
    }

return $ev;
```

The error for this code :

> {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined index:
>   keyword","file":"/var/www/stage/app/controllers/EventController.php","line":48}}

if I change

```
foreach($cronEvent as $result){
        $ev =  $result['keyword'];
    }

return $ev;
```

to

```
return $cronEvent;
```

(just delete the foreach loop and rename the returning variable), I have this error :

> {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Object of class
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to
>   string","file":"/var/www/stage/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php","line":361}}

So, how can access to my data in the object ? Maybe my Query Builder implementation doesn't works...

Thanks for any help !

Comment: `$cronEvent` is a query builder object, not a result set. you need to call `get()`, `first()` or `paginate()` to get the result.

Comment: Yeah, sure. It was a mistake from me... i'm so dumb ahah. It works good now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is missing `get()` at the end of that query builder, thus you don't run the query at all. That's it.

Comment: I'm so stupid sometimes... 1 hour lost for that mistake. Thanks so. It works great now !